# Can we set a GraphQL query's result to conditionally return either a boolean or a custom object type?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm attempting to write a graphql query that checks for the existence of a record. The target behavior here is that it returns the record if it exists, and false if it does not. *(I'm purposely trying to avoid it returning an error if the record does not exist)*. I tried something like this:

```
union VerifyExistenceResult = Boolean | TheRecordType

verifyRecordExists(recordUrl: String!): VerifyExistenceResult!
```

but unions don't seem to support having scalars. Is there a better approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can definetely do that. You can declare a variable in your code whose outcome is a boolean.Afterwards , in your gql query , you can create a directive , who returns the field you want. If the boolean returns negative , that field is never queried. (Docs for apollo directives : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/directives/)

Comment: Thanks! I looked up directives but didn't really understand how to use them for this scenario.. any chance you could help me with an example?

Comment: @VishnuNarayanan I have just posted another answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the following gql Query.

```
const GET_RECORD=gql`
 query ($skipRecord:Boolean!){
 recordUrl
}
 `
```

Then, you would have to declare a local variable, named, for example, localSkipRecord.

Now, when you actually are using the query, say with the hook , you have to pass this:

```
{data,loading,error}=useMutation(GET_RECORD,{
 variables:{skipRecord:localSkipRecord}
})
```